# anaconda Boot install from lvm

Tags: anaconda, lvm, grub2

I am installing Fedora 31, via tftp. My system has 3 disks: sda - the disk to install onto; sdb/sdc are in a `lvm` vg group (VG1) that has an one lv (lv1). This lv has the F31 disk image (.iso), as well as a kickstart file.

Question: how to boot anaconda with this setup? `vmlinuz`  and `initrd` images are pulled from the original F31 install DVD (and copied to the tftp server).

A little more specific: how to tell grub to set the root path to VG1/lv1?

Do I need to generate a new `vmlinuz` and `initrd` (maybe needing to add the `lvm` kernel module)?

FWIW: Thie same install via `nfs` works fine. For this install, though, I need to access the install/kickstart setup from the VG/lv attached to the same system.

TIA

ken

Answer (score -1):

After weeks/months of playing with this, and even listing it as a bug, I found that this is not possible with Fedora versions 32 or less (at this time, F33 is still rawhide, and not publicly released).

You can boot the kernel from an lv using `inst.repo=hd:<any mountable device>:path` . The `<any mountable device>`  can be an lv, or any other device, specified by `UUID=xxx`, or `LABEL=xxx`. Fedora 33 anaconda kickstart harddrive command now acts like that.

Hope this helps someone in the future.